# How to Convert a search string into a LINQ Query?

Tags: regex, string, linq

How to Convert a search string into a LINQ Query.

The delimiters are always AND,OR,(,)
Say I have search string inputs as:

1. abc AND xcv OR cvb OR pqr
2. (abc AND pqr) OR zxc OR try
3. pqr OR ter AND (asd OR tor)

I want to build a LINQ query based on this.
Example Output(for case 3):
1. where value = "pqr" OR value="ter" AND (value="asd" OR value="tor")

How can we achieve these kinds of segregation for a string.

Comment: It is a small project. You need to build a simple interpreter to parse the grammar and then user Expression Tree to generate the Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into `System.Linq.Dynamic`.  Seems to have the functionality you want.

> **Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)**
>
> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Otherwise you can parse the expression yourself and generate an expression tree.

> **Dynamic LINQ Queries with Expression Trees**
>
> https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/